# Angular 4 : ng build --prod takes up more than 80 mins

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I have an angular app (/src is hardly 8MB), when i try doing a production build it takes up more than 80 mins to complete the build process.
Need suggestions to improve the build speed.

> ng --version

```
@angular/cli: 1.4.3
node: 8.9.1
os: linux x64
@angular/animations: 4.3.5
@angular/common: 4.3.5
@angular/compiler: 4.3.5
@angular/core: 4.3.5
@angular/forms: 4.3.5
@angular/http: 4.3.5
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.5
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.5
@angular/router: 4.3.5
@angular/cli: 1.4.3
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.5
typescript: 2.2.2
```

> **/src $** find . -type f  | sed -e 's/.*.//' | sort | uniq -c

```
3   css
2   eot
4   gif
1   gitkeep
212 html
2   ico
1   jpg
1   js
3   json
9   png
213 scss
48  svg
370 ts
2   ttf
2   woff
```

> node --max-old-space-size=4096 node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod
>   --env=prod --base-href --verbose

```
4007ms building modules                         
1ms module and chunk tree optimization 
581ms chunk modules optimization
0ms advanced chunk modules optimization 
0ms module reviving 
18ms module order optimization
4ms module id optimization 
0ms chunk reviving 
8ms chunk order optimization 
33ms chunk id optimization
1002ms hashing
0ms module assets processing 
16779ms chunk assets processing
6ms additional chunk assets processing 
2ms recording 
0ms additional asset processing 
4803967ms chunk asset optimization
7737ms asset optimization
222514ms emitting
```

Comment: they are many compiler performances improvement in the version 5 of angular. Have you estimate the burden to upgrade your application to v5 ?

Comment: @PierreMallet I tried upgrading the Angular CLI to 1.6.2 (from 1.4.3). I had the same issue. Anyhow i will try upgrading the Angular app itself to 5 as it says "Angular compiler is improved to enable faster builds and rebuilds in Angular 5".

Comment: Removing `--prod` meta flag speeds up the build process, but the resulting build size is two times large.

Comment: please share your webpack config

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the build speed issue, I missed out the `--base-href <base>`

The following ng build command works fine now:

```
node --max-old-space-size=7000 node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --env=prod --base-href .
```